# Removing rows with zeros in x% of columns

Tags: r

I am trying to filter dataframes by removing rows which have zero's in 
at-least 70 % of the columns.

I know how to remove rows if the row have all zero values. Would really appreciate if you help me with this conditional filtering.

This is what I have come up with:

```
keep <- CountFrame[rowSums(CountFrame==0),]
```

Comment: `CountFrame[rowSums(CountFrame == 0) / ncol(CountFrame) >= 0.7, ]`  ?